# Continuously check if website is available with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a server running a website that for some reason just drops dead whenever it feels like it. Not sure why and i know this solution I´m going to describe is just a way of putting out the fire and not solving the problem. But for now that´s ok.

So, i want to run a Powershellscript on the server that continuosly checks if the website is available or not and based on that perform some magic to get it running again.

So far i have this code.

When i turn on the Apache and runs the script, the function "running" is working.
When i turn off the Apache and runs the script, the function "notrunning" is working.

But the problem is, when i start the Apache, run the script and "running" is continuosly looping and i turn of the Apache (script still running) i want it to go on to "notrunning", fix the problem, start my service again and check from the start if the site is up and go to "running". But it get stuck on "running" and wont change to "notrunning".

Any idea how i can make this happen?

(I edited the script to take out the real process and service name for my companys sake)

```
function checkSite
{
[string] $url = 'http://websitegoeshere.com'
[net.httpWebRequest] $req = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
$req.Method = "HEAD"
[net.httpWebResponse] $res = $req.getResponse()
while ($res.StatusCode -ge "200") {running} notrunning
}

function running
{
cls;
Write-Host "  -=IS-checker=-" -fore yellow
Write-Host "" -fore green
Write-Host "----------------------" -fore green
Write-Host " Access to web = OK " -fore green
Write-Host "----------------------" -fore green
sleep 60
}
function notrunning
{
cls;
Write-Host "-=IS-checker=-" -fore yellow
Write-Host "" -fore red
Write-Host "-------------------------" -fore red
Write-Host "  Site down - Site Down  " -fore red
Write-Host "-------------------------" -fore red
sleep 2
$process = "process-name-goes-here"
Write-Host "Stopping process" $process -fore red 
Stop-Process -processname $process
sleep 5
$service = "service-name-goes-here"
Write-Host "Killing service" $service -fore red
Stop-Service $service -Force
sleep 5
Write-Host "Starting service" $service -fore green
Start-Service $service
sleep 5
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss"
$LogFile = 'C:\PSLog\'+"LOG_"+$LogTime+".log"
$LogTime+" Stopped "+$process+", Stopped "+$service+", Started "+$service | Out-File $LogFile
Write-Host "Logfile written to"$LogFile -fore green
sleep 5
checkSite
}
```

checkSite

Comment: There are tools that you can get (some are even free/open source, [others](http://www.paessler.com/network_monitoring/website_monitoring) have paid versions you might need to upgrade to) that will monitor a website for you an trigger an alert or take other actions when it doesn't respond. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I just started learning Powershell and thought it would be fun to create something useful :)

Comment: Rule #1: Don't create something that someone has already written (and provided at no/low cost) unless it's purely an educational exercise. They've probably done it better - which could become important in a business situation.

Answer (score 0):

First: If this is for anything other than an exercise in using Powershell, i agree with Alroc: find a free/opensource tool/system (Nagios is my preferred for this exercise, as it can execute Powershell scripts from an agent on a windows box).

However, If you're intent on using Powershell as an exercise, try the Powershell ScheduledJob module cmdlets, which can be used to control the Task Scheduler from inside a Powershell script.

Powershell doesnt have its own scheduler, so most of the time I use the Windows Task Scheduler execute scripts on a regular basis.

Essentially you'll want to write a script that can be executed with a command-line execution (lookup Param to send command line varaibles to your script) and then setup a scheduled task to execute the script on a schedule. The alerting would need to be handled either in the Scheduled Task or within the script itself (I suggest within the script itself if you want to avoid a TON of false-positive alerts).

As nothing is truly "continuous" in the automation world (even Event/Trigger have ms delays), you could set the iteration of the check to something super small (1minute); however for a website uptime check, once every 5min is (generally) considered very frequent (normally 10-30min depending on the criticality of the site). Play around with the HTTP

Here's a great wrightup on how to use the Powershell ScheduledJob module cmdlets. 
As you already have functions to do the tasks you want, this should be very easy to wrap them into a job.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job.aspx

Here's some other sources for Website monitoring with Powershell:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/otto/archive/2007/08/23/quick-and-dirty-web-site-monitoring-with-powershell.aspx

http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/monitor-web-site-availability/

If you want to get into more detailed and creative ways to automate website tests (besides a 200/available test), check out the Autobrowse Powershell module: http://autobrowse.start-automating.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the standpoint of this just being a practice exercise, your endless loop is being caused by this line:

while ($res.StatusCode -ge "200") {running} notrunning

Note that nothing in the 'running' function changes $res, so it will always be whatever value it started with, and it will simply keep executing the 'running' function over and over again waiting for it to change.

Comment: But i want it to start with function checkSite and see if the page is up or not, take action based on that (running/notrunning) and after that start over with a new checkSite. I don´t want the running/notrunning to change the $res. I want the script to make a new check like "Ok, it was not up 5 minutes ago, how about now? I will check again. Ok, yeah, now it´s up"